# How do I create an async timer in Python?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

I want to create a 30sec timer in Python with `async` but I don't know how I can do.

I tried with this code but it blocks all the code:

```py
def restore_presences(self, loop):
    async def func():
        db, c = self.connect()
        c.execute('SELECT Presenza FROM Teachers')
        presences = c.fetchall()
        for item in presences:
            c.execute('UPDATE Teachers SET Presenza = ?', ('no',))
            db.commit()
        db.close()

    threading.Thread(target=lambda loop: loop.run_until_complete(func()), args=(loop,)).start()


# THIS BLOCKS MY CODE
t = Timer(30, self.restore_presences, args=[asyncio.get_event_loop()])
t.start()
t.join()
# THIS BLOCKS MY CODE
```

The `async` function runs perfectly.

Comment: Do not call join if you dont want to wait for the thread...That just to begin with. Why are you using both async and threading?

Comment: Ok, thanks. But can I save the timer so when I close the program and I reopen it, it continue? Ex. 30s timer. I close the program and when I open it after 10s the timer is 20s.

Comment: Well, you can save the timer counter and start it again from the last counter point...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to timeout an async test in pytest with fixture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55684737/how-to-timeout-an-async-test-in-pytest-with-fixture)