# How to timeout an async test in pytest with fixture?

Tags: python, pytest, python-asyncio, pytest-asyncio

I am testing an async function that might get deadlocked. I tried to add a fixture to limit the function to only run for 5 seconds before raising a failure, but it hasn't worked so far.

Setup:

```
pipenv --python==3.6
pipenv install pytest==4.4.1
pipenv install pytest-asyncio==0.10.0
```

Code:

```py
import asyncio
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def my_fixture():
  # attempt to start a timer that will stop the test somehow
  asyncio.ensure_future(time_limit())
  yield 'eggs'


async def time_limit():
  await asyncio.sleep(5)
  print('time limit reached')     # this isn't printed
  raise AssertionError


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test(my_fixture):
  assert my_fixture == 'eggs'
  await asyncio.sleep(10)
  print('this should not print')  # this is printed
  assert 0
```

--

Edit: Mikhail's solution works fine. I can't find a way to incorporate it into a fixture, though.

Comment: You can't await the test in a fixture with `pytest-asyncio`. Mikhail's answer is the only solution, I'm afraid. Good question though.

Comment: In my tests I use [the following hook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70095871/7691729) to add the desired functionality. It works quite well for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Convenient way to limit function (or block of code) with timeout is to use [async-timeout](https://pypi.org/project/async_timeout/) module. You can use it inside your test function or, for example, create a decorator. Unlike with fixture it'll allow to specify concrete time for each test:

```
import asyncio
import pytest
from async_timeout import timeout


def with_timeout(t):
    def wrapper(corofunc):
        async def run(*args, **kwargs):
            with timeout(t):
                return await corofunc(*args, **kwargs)
        return run       
    return wrapper


@pytest.mark.asyncio
@with_timeout(2)
async def test_sleep_1():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    assert 1 == 1


@pytest.mark.asyncio
@with_timeout(2)
async def test_sleep_3():
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    assert 1 == 1
```

It's not hard to create decorator for concrete time (`with_timeout_5 = partial(with_timeout, 5)`).

---

I don't know how to create texture (if you really need fixture), but code above can provide starting point. Also not sure if there's a common way to achieve goal better.

Comment: This works, but it isn't a fixture, which fits into the pytest system better and can be applied to every test function in a package automatically. I think I'll use this approach in my code for now. I'll wait a couple day before I mark this as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to use fixtures for timeout, one just needs to add the following hook into `conftest.py`.

- Any fixture prefixed with `timeout` must return a number of seconds(`int`, `float`) the test can run.
- The closest fixture w.r.t scope is chosen. `autouse` fixtures have lesser priority than explicitly chosen ones. Later one is preferred. Unfortunately order in the function argument list does NOT matter.
- If there is no such fixture, the test is not restricted and will run indefinitely as usual.
- The test must be marked with `pytest.mark.asyncio` too, but that is needed anyway.

```py
# Add to conftest.py
import asyncio

import pytest

_TIMEOUT_FIXTURE_PREFIX = "timeout"


@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_setup(item: pytest.Item):
    """Wrap all tests marked with pytest.mark.asyncio with their specified timeout.

    Must run as early as possible.

    Parameters
    ----------
    item : pytest.Item
        Test to wrap
    """
    yield
    orig_obj = item.obj
    timeouts = [n for n in item.funcargs if n.startswith(_TIMEOUT_FIXTURE_PREFIX)]
    # Picks the closest timeout fixture if there are multiple
    tname = None if len(timeouts) == 0 else timeouts[-1]

    # Only pick marked functions
    if item.get_closest_marker("asyncio") is not None and tname is not None:

        async def new_obj(*args, **kwargs):
            """Timed wrapper around the test function."""
            try:
                return await asyncio.wait_for(
                    orig_obj(*args, **kwargs), timeout=item.funcargs[tname]
                )
            except Exception as e:
                pytest.fail(f"Test {item.name} did not finish in time.")

        item.obj = new_obj
```

Example:

```
@pytest.fixture
def timeout_2s():
    return 2


@pytest.fixture(scope="module", autouse=True)
def timeout_5s():
    # You can do whatever you need here, just return/yield a number
    return 5


async def test_timeout_1():
    # Uses timeout_5s fixture by default
    await aio.sleep(0)  # Passes
    return 1


async def test_timeout_2(timeout_2s):
    # Uses timeout_2s because it is closest
    await aio.sleep(5)  # Timeouts
```

**WARNING**

Might not work with some other plugins, I have only tested it with `pytest-asyncio`, it definitely won't work if `item` is redefined by some hook.

Comment: This would be a great addition to `pytest-asyncio` :)

Comment: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-asyncio/issues/215

Answer (score 2):

I just *loved* [Quimby's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70095871/292586) of marking tests with timeouts. Here's my attempt to improve it, using [pytest marks](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/mark.html):

```
# tests/conftest.py
import asyncio


@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_pyfunc_call(pyfuncitem: pytest.Function):
    """
    Wrap all tests marked with pytest.mark.async_timeout with their specified timeout.
    """
    orig_obj = pyfuncitem.obj

    if marker := pyfuncitem.get_closest_marker("async_timeout"):

        async def new_obj(*args, **kwargs):
            """Timed wrapper around the test function."""
            try:
                return await asyncio.wait_for(orig_obj(*args, **kwargs), timeout=marker.args[0])
            except (asyncio.CancelledError, asyncio.TimeoutError):
                pytest.fail(f"Test {pyfuncitem.name} did not finish in time.")

        pyfuncitem.obj = new_obj

    yield


def pytest_configure(config: pytest.Config):
    config.addinivalue_line("markers", "async_timeout(timeout): cancels the test execution after the specified amount of seconds")
```

Usage:

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
@pytest.mark.async_timeout(10)
async def potentially_hanging_function():
    await asyncio.sleep(20)
```

It should not be hard to include this to the [`asyncio` mark on `pytest-asyncio`](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-asyncio/blob/v0.20.2/pytest_asyncio/plugin.py#L416-L488), so we can get a syntax like:

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio(timeout=10)
async def potentially_hanging_function():
    await asyncio.sleep(20)
```

EDIT: looks like [there's already a PR for that](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-asyncio/pull/216).

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! I've made a small improvement because in case the test fails with a CancelledError / TimeoutError, the test will fail for the "wrong" reason instead of displaying the actual traceback. It's present here: https://gist.github.com/romuald/6220df8f3333f042c1cd4454f03588dc feel free to incorporate it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a fixture, I solved it this way using a decorator:

```py
def timeout(delay):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        async def new_func(*args, **kwargs):
            async with asyncio.timeout(delay):
                return await func(*args, **kwargs)

        return new_func

    return decorator
    

@pytest.mark.asyncio
@timeout(3)
async def test_forever_fails():
    await asyncio.Future()
```

**Requires python 3.11**

Or I believe `trio` provides something like this for earlier python versions.